# "Printing Label with Dymo 450 with java program: Image Discrepancy and Blank Offset Issue"

Tags: java, printing, measurement, dymo

this is the first time i worked with a labelwriter in java. I made a program to put strings and qr codes and barcodes on a png file, that gets printed afterwards. my approach was creating a bufferedImage and drawing that onto the file with imageio. what confuses me that the image that gets printed looks different than the image that i saved in a .png, and there is always a blank offset on the left side. I think i need to use a different width and height for the bufferedimage. So i tried researching how to figure out the width and height, but I still am sitting at this problem. I tried figuring out how the printing works, and also used different widths, and heights, but it never worked. Even if the image is generated correctly. i also looked at similar problems on internet forums, but it did not work for me.The labelwriter im using is the dymo 450, and it has loaded 89mm(width) 36mm (height) labels (also from dymo). I would really appreciate help, im quite stuck on this. How can i calculate the width and height? Or did i do something else wrong? If you need further information to help ill provide it.

Looking forward to hear from you!